# Align text with center of picture in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Members}
\begin{columns}[T] 
\hfill
\begin{column}{.32\textwidth}
\hspace{2mm} \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{john.jpg} \hspace{2mm} John\\
\hspace{2mm} \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{jane.jpg} \hspace{2mm} Jane\\
\hspace{2mm} \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{sue.jpg} \hspace{2mm} Sue\\
\hspace{2mm} \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{bob.jpg} \hspace{2mm} Bob\\
\end{column}
\hfill
\begin{column}{.32\textwidth}
Middle Part
\end{column}
\hfill
\begin{column}{.32\textwidth}
Right Part
\end{column}
\hfill
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm placing four pictures vertically next to each other, and I want to put their names to the right of the corresponding picture. The problem is that the name is aligned with the bottom of the picture. Can I make it align with the center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I use a `\raisebox` wrapped inside a macro named `\Includegraphics` (capital "I").  The key is knowing the proper downward vertical shift of the image, which is otherwise aligned to the baseline.  That shift, in this case, is `-.5\dimexpr\height-\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox`, which will work regardless of image height and font size.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\newcommand\Includegraphics[2][]{%
  \raisebox{-.5\dimexpr\height-\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Members}
\begin{columns}[T] 
\hfill
\begin{column}{.32\textwidth}
\hspace{2mm}\Includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image} \hspace{2mm} John\\
\hspace{2mm}\Includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-A} \hspace{2mm} Jane\\
\hspace{2mm}\Includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-B} \hspace{2mm} Sue\\
\hspace{2mm}\Includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-C} \hspace{2mm} Bob\\
\end{column}
\hfill
\begin{column}{.32\textwidth}
Middle Part
\end{column}
\hfill
\begin{column}{.32\textwidth}
Right Part
\end{column}
\hfill
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]