# align text and image in beamer

Tags: beamer, minipage

I am trying to centrally align text and an image. I tried using minipage, but nothing is working. (I cant use sidecaption as the text is a part of \only environment in actual problem)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
    Single site scattering
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[draft]{../../Preambles/thanks.png}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

NB. I tried to put picture with draft graphicx package, but its clashing with beamer. Kindly allow a hardcoded pic.

Comment: Duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306580/align-text-with-center-of-picture-in-beamer

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is working"? If you remove the `[t]` option in both minipages, then the text and the image get vertically centered relative to each other. Is that the desired result? (what do you mean by "centrally align"?)

Answer (score 2):

Taking the lead from the answer cited in my comment and centering the text `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\Includegraphics[2][]{%
  \raisebox{-.5\dimexpr\height-\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.3\textwidth}
    Single site scattering
  \end{minipage}
    \Includegraphics[draft]{../../Preambles/thanks.png}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]